# How can I use same domain for two website using subdirectories?

Tags: nginx, url-routing, subdirectory

How to create a proxy reverse server for domain sub directries. I have a main website built on nextjs and hosted on firebase. Now i also have wordpress blog website hosted on hostinger. I want that "whitepanda.io" when use goes in this domain the main website will show up and when user goes "whitepana.io/blogs" this subdirectory then the wordpress website will show up remember the when explore the blog website the domain should be same. How can achive this kind of stuff.

What tried Already Created a proxy server:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name whitepanda.io;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://whitepanda-6c4b2.web.app/;
    }

    location /blogs/ {
        proxy_pass https://trywhitepanda.com/;
    }
}
```

whenever i go to http://localhost/ it's giving me 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Make an upstreams for the Wordpress server and the Next.js. It also might be helpful to have the Wordpress installed within a subdirectory with the same path name i.e. `/blog` so you don't have to deal with rewriting rules. The config should look something like this,

```
upstream nextjs_upstream {
    server localhost:3000;  # Change the port if your Next.js app is running on a different port
}

upstream wordpress_upstream {
    server localhost:8000;  # Change the port if your WordPress instance is running on a different port
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.com;

    # Next.js configuration
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    # WordPress configuration
    location /blog {
        proxy_pass http://wordpress_upstream;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # Additional WordPress-specific configuration if needed
        # ...

        # Prevent PHP execution in this location
        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to have Next.js and WordPress already installed and running on your server. Adjust any additional WordPress-specific configuration if necessary.

Comment: I added those configs but when go to localhost it's showing the main website but when i go the "/blogs" route its giving me "Oops, looks like the page is lost.
This is not a fault, just an accident that was not intentional." this error note "https://trywhitepanda.com/blogs/" this is the wordpress website